# How To Use Entity Framework with database first and identity columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I´ve got a simple database with a couple of tables which are linked with foreign keys. Each table got an "id" column with Identity Property and autoincrement enabled. From this Database I generated a Model in VS2015. If I now try to Insert new Data in an MVC 5 Web Application, I get an Error, which says that NULL Values can´t be Inserted on the "id" column. So I wonder why it even tries to. It should be auto incremented by the database. In the Mapping the Parameters are:

```
Entity Key = true
Nullable = False (it´s integer, so it can´t be Nullable)
StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity
Type = Int32
```

The Model itself is just the auto generated class:

```
namespace project.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class projectClass
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public projectClass()
        {
            this.plan = new HashSet<plan>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string targetName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<plan> plan { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Controller is auto generated too:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,targetName,created,updated,CategoryId")] projectClass projectClass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.projectClass.Add(projectClass);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.trainingCategoryId = new SelectList(db.projectClass, "id", "shortDescription", projectClass.CategoryId);
        return View(projectClass);
    }
```

I really have no Idea why the id column is inserted, and where to change it.

Comment: Where are you declaring trainingTarget?

Comment: this was just a copy & paste error. I edited the code. Should be "projectClass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. It was an database issue. I tried to INSERT a row manually, wich failed also. So i found a badly written trigger on this table wich caused the exception.